# Export Json data to an excel file using Angular 4

Tags: json, excel, angular, typescript

I have an Array List of objects. I want to export those data to an Excel file (.xlsx or .xls).

The template of the Excel file is also given. What needs to be done is only mapping to an existing Excel file. The Excel file is located in the Angular project itself. How can I achieve this using Angular 4.

```json
[
   {
      "name": "Roshan",
      "age": "35"
   },
   {
      "name": "Ritika",
      "age": "29"
   }
]
```

The above data should be map to an Excel of having column names are `Employee_Name` and `Employee_age`.

Comment: You can use xlsx and filesaver packages to achieve

Comment: you can find a solution from the [article: Exporting an Excel file in Angular](https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try xlsx package

install xlsx to your project

```
 npm install xlsx --save
```

---

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
 import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelExportService {
    constructor() { }

    public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(json);
        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
        const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
        this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
    }

    private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
        const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
            type: EXCEL_TYPE
        });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
    }
}
```

---

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  data: any = [{
    eid: 'e101',
    ename: 'ravi',
    esal: 1000
  },
  {
    eid: 'e102',
    ename: 'ram',
    esal: 2000
  },
  {
    eid: 'e103',
    ename: 'rajesh',
    esal: 3000
  }];
  constructor(private excelService:ExcelExportService ){

  }
  exportAsXLSX():void {
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.data, 'sample');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx for sharing the answer,But i am unable to add any styling component to the cell. Can you tell by which module i can achieve it.

Comment: @Harshita I have added a method to download excel with formatting, you can add formatting according to that

Answer (score 0):

`You can export multiple sheets to an excel file using this code. First I created a service file and created a method` **exportAsExcelFile()** `This method code is included below.` **fileInfo** `is the object that I am including in the code section.`

```
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
 export class ExcelExportServiceService {

 constructor() { }
public exportAsExcelFile(fileInfo: ExportFileInfo): void {
const workbook:  XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
fileInfo.templates.forEach((x)=>{
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, 
    XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(x.data), x.sheetName);
});
XLSX.writeFile(
  wb,
  `${fileInfo.fileName}`
);
}

export interface ExportFileInfo{
 fileName:string;
 templates:ExportTemplateInfo[];
 }
  export interface ExportTemplateInfo{
  data:any;
  sheetName:string;
 }

 constructor(private exportService: ExcelExportServiceService) {}
excelFileExportFromJson(){
let data:any[]=[];
this.analysisDrugList.forEach(x=>{
  data.push({
    'NDC-9':x.ndc.substring(0,9),
    'Canister':x.drawerType==='Smart'?'SMART':x.canisterLocation,
    'Drug Name':x.name,
    'Strength':x.strength,
    'Manufacturer':x.manufacturer,
    'NDC-11':x.ndc,
    'CustomerNDC':x.customerDrugNdc,
    'CItem#':x.atpCanisterNumber,
  })
})
this.fileInfo={
  fileName: `test_file_name.xlsx`,
  templates:[{
  data:data,
  sheetName:`test_sheet`
  }]}
this.exportService.exportAsExcelFile(this.fileInfo);
  }
```